# How to skip or modify a field while dumping a json file in Python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I'm dumping a MongoDB databse in Python in json format. Here's part of my code

```
cursor = collection.find()

with open(json_file_path, 'w') as outfile:
    dump = json.dumps([doc for doc in cursor], sort_keys=False, indent=4, default=json_util.default)
    outfile.write(dump)
```

The problem is that pymongo adds an `_id` filed by itself and creates an entry like `"_id": {"$oid": "5c2b4813e43eda7815444204"}`. This creates an error that `key '$oid' must not start with '$'` while loading from this json file. So I was thinking if I could either modify or skip this field all together while exporting the database itself? How can I do that?

```
{
    "Employee ID": 9771504, 
    "NAME": "Harsh Wardhan", 
    "DOB": "14-Apr", 
    "MOBILE": 12345697890, 
    "Group": "SW-VS", 
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c2b4813e43eda7815444204"
    }, 
    "Emai ID": "hwardhan@examples.com"
}
```

Comment: the sample you provided, is that 1 `doc`? (aka, is the id field added for each doc?)

Comment: In the above example I have given just 1 doc but there are many such docs. And the id field is added for each doc.

Comment: Why don't you just change the name / skip the field before encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the extra id is added for each entry in the cursor, you can just filter it out before writing using a dict comprehension.

```
cursor = collection.find()

with open(json_file_path, 'w') as outfile:
    dump = json.dumps([{k:v for k,v in doc.items() if k != "_id"} for doc in cursor],
                      sort_keys=False, indent=4, default=json_util.default)
    outfile.write(dump)
```

Comment: One question though. It is appending duplicate rows to the json file on each run.

Comment: if you open your json file in `w` write mode as you did, then no, the file gets overwritten.